# Spring boot converter validation - were to put it and how?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, type-conversion

I am using spring boot converter for REST controller but I need to validate data before converting it.

I tried to put `@Valid` annotation to converter's `convert` method but got this:

> nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException:
> HV000151: A method overriding another method must not redefine the
> parameter constraint configuration, but method
> MyCustomConverter#convert(String) redefines the configuration of
> Converter#convert(Object)

What's the best way to implement this validation?

Comment: You cannot, you can only validate after conversions.

Comment: But if I need to - do I need to put the validation to the converter?

Comment: No because you simply cannot. Next to that you shouldn't mix concerns, a converter converts, not validates.

Comment: `@Valid` is what you might put on incoming entities in your controller or at fields of the incoming entities.